# Meteor Login doesn't work when deployed to *.meteor.com

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have the following code on my Meteor app. 
main.js (partial):

```
Template.login.events({
    'click .login-button': function( e ) {
        var serviceName = e.currentTarget.id.replace( 'login-buttons-', '' );
        Accounts._loginButtonsSession.resetMessages();

        var loginWithService = Meteor["loginWith" + (serviceName === 'meteor-developer' ? 'MeteorDeveloperAccount' : capitalize(serviceName))];
        var options = {}; // use default scope unless specified
        if (Accounts.ui._options.requestPermissions[serviceName])
            options.requestPermissions = Accounts.ui._options.requestPermissions[serviceName];
        if (Accounts.ui._options.requestOfflineToken[serviceName])
            options.requestOfflineToken = Accounts.ui._options.requestOfflineToken[serviceName];
        if (Accounts.ui._options.forceApprovalPrompt[serviceName])
            options.forceApprovalPrompt = Accounts.ui._options.forceApprovalPrompt[serviceName];

        loginWithService(options, function (err) {
            console.log('user logged in');
        });
    }
})
```

And index.html (partial):

```
<div class="service-login-buttons">
    <div class="login-text-and-button">
        <div class="login-button single-login-button" id="login-buttons-twitter">
            <div class="login-image" id="login-buttons-image-twitter"></div>
            <span class="text-besides-image sign-in-text-twitter">Sign in to save your Pomodoros</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On the localhost it works just fine (twitter login). 
I changed the twitter app settings to point to  the correct *.meteor.com address, 
 but the button doesn't do anything (no errors either).

 Is there perhaps some configuration I need to redo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple: I had to configure the Twitter API on the deployed version as well. 
Since I was using custom login buttons, I simply added

```
{{> loginButtons }}
```

To get the configuration dialog (where the API keys are added), then removed that part after configuration was done.